# wget wont download zip files

Tags: curl, wget

wget

I've been trying to get all the .zip files downloaded locally from a site, wget seems to fetch everything except the .zip files I actually want;

e.g.

```
% wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --domains example.org --no-parent https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/spot/monthly/trades/1INCHBTC/
```

this downloads a single html file into the local "data.binance.vision" directory.

```
% s data.binance.vision/
index.html@prefix=data%2Fspot%2Fmonthly%2Ftrades%2F1INCHBTC%2F.html
```

Can anybody assist? I'm open to using any utility (curl?) that will download the files locally for me.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --domains example.org --no-parent https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/spot/monthly/trades/1INCHBTC/
```

command as-is is limited to `example.org` domain (`--domains example.org`) which might explains why it refuses to download anything other than page pointed by url. Please try using correct `--domains` corresponding to site, i.e. `binance.vision`